# Post array automatically to one page at another

Tags: php, arrays, send

I have a search bar on my site that invokes a script that makes queries in database.

Once the queries are finished I would like to return the result to the first page but:

I do not want to go through a session, because the user could have several tabs open, and I do not want to pass the result in the url with a serialize because the result is really not pretty in the search bar.

Would you have an idea how to pass an array from one page to another, without using ajax?

I send a value with : search.php

```
<form action="../core/data_search.php" method="post" id="research_form">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" id="research" />
</form>
```

My research script is :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("conf.php");

$id = $_SESSION["id"];
if ($_POST && !empty($_POST)) {
    $data = $_POST['search'];
    //Recherche d'une adresse mail
    if ( preg_match ( " /^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/ " , $data) ){
        $column = "WHERE `email` = '$data' AND `add_by_user` = '$id'";
    //Recherche d'un code postal complet (ou la recherche strictement égal à la colonne)    
    }elseif (preg_match(" /^(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-5])(?:\d{3})?)|97[1-8]|98[4-9]|2[abAB])$/ ", $data)) {
        $column = "WHERE `zip_code` LIKE '$data%' AND `add_by_user` = '$id'";
    }elseif (preg_match(" /^([a-zA-Z]+[ '-]?[a-zA-Z]+){1,30}$/ ", $data)) {
        $column = "WHERE `first_name` = '$data' OR `last_name` = '$data' AND `add_by_user` = '$id'";
    //Recherche par date de fin de formation
    }elseif (preg_match(" /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/ ", $data)) {
        $column = "WHERE `end_formation_date` = '$data' AND `add_by_user` = '$id' ";
    }else{
        header("Location : ../search.php?return=error");
        exit();
    }

    $data = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM customers $column ");
    $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Here i replace the end of script for use Ajax
    if($result){
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I need to have this type of result in search.php

```
<form action="../core/data_search.php" method="post" id="research_form">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" id="research" />
</form>
<section>
    <p>firstname : <?=$firstname?> <!--received to my queries script--></p>
    <p>lastname  : <?=$lastname?> <!--received to my queries script--></p>
    <p>age       : <?=$age?> <!--received to my queries script--></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Confusing explanation, could you provide us with some code samples?

Comment: Just add the form at the bottom of the php file? And check if you have received post data and the query proceeded then display firstname, lastname and age. If you have not received post data, then just display the form.

Comment: An example of how I handle post data and display html output when needed: https://pastebin.com/uPGXEfMz

Comment: Thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score -1):

When queries completed results are already stored in a variable. So you can display on page.

If you want to transfer it to another page, you can store the serialized array into HTML hidden form element. 
This requires user to submit the form to pass the array to next page.

Comment: But i don't want to any person stay on this page, it's just a queries script ;)